# Adding nil value to lua table

Tags: c, lua, null, lua-table

I want to sent a luatable via the c lua library. This works fine for values, but i have troubles when inserting a nil. Inserting a nil removes the data from the received JSON data.

Sending a value works fine:

```
lua_pushnumber(&luaState, 2.5);
lua_rawseti(&luaState, -2, 1);
```

When inserting a Nil instead of the number, both the index and the Nil are not received.

```
lua_pushnil(&luaState);
lua_rawseti(&luaState, -2, 1);
```

Apparantly a table in Lua is an array that accepts not only numbers as
indices, but also strings or any other value of the language (except nil).

I added multiple numbers and empty fields with indeces in the table and all empty fields dissapeared including their index value. Even if the last value was a number.

For entering:

```
lua_pushnumber(&luaState, 0);
lua_rawseti(&luaState, -2, 0);
lua_pushnil(&luaState);
lua_rawseti(&luaState, -2, 1);
lua_pushnumber(&luaState, 2);
lua_rawseti(&luaState, -2, 2);
```

I got the following result: `{"0":0,"2":2}}` while i want the following result `{"0":0,"1":null,"2":2}}`

Adding a string value for null does not work, cause it gives the null quotation marks. {} ends up in 0 values.

How can i get an index with null in the result?

Comment: please provide more context if my answer is not satisfactory. are you trying to serialize a Lua table, created in C with some JSON library?  what is the actual output? what is the expected output? share more code

Answer (score 0):

Why would you receive a nil value? `{[1] = nil}` is an empty table. So you cannot expect any table fields in your json string.
I assume you expected `[null]`

Create a table like `{nil, 2.5}` if you want to see an output like `[null, 2.5]`. An empty table has infinite nil values. You'll understand that would be difficult to serialize explicitly.

This assumes you're using dkjson. Other Json libraries might result in other representations for nil.